# Calling WPF from Native C++ application causes async calls to loose the context

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, async-await

I'm calling a C# WPF Dialog from a Win32 native application by using a CLI wrapper. We have some other dialogs which work fine, this one however is showing some peculiar behavior - it's also more complex than the others.

Well, from beginning on, after the CLI C++ code calls the C# code, we set the context by calling:

```
        var currentContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

        if (currentContext == null && (Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't set a dispatcher sync context on thread pool threads");
        }

        SynchronizationContext context = null;
        // WPF needs to make sure that all GUI actions are done on the main GUI thread.
        // As we are beeing called by Unmanaged C++ there is no SynchronizationContext set.            
        // This check make sure we will be back to the GUI thread after an await

        if (currentContext == null)
        {
            context = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext();
            if (logger != null)
            {
                logger.Trace(string.Format("Applying DispatcherSyncContext on thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            }

            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);

            Debug.Assert(Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread.CurrentThread) != null);
        }
        else if (!(currentContext is DispatcherSynchronizationContext))
        {
            LogWarning(
                "Current SynchronizationContext is not a DispatcherSynchronizationContext and may cause exceptions. Current context: " + currentContext,
                logger);
            context = currentContext;
        }
```

I'm not sure if we should be checking for the Dispatcher and not for the context, but as far as i Know, this should work.

Well, it does - most of the time.

There is a async call to load data from the DB which looks like this:

```
public async Task<bool> AddStuff(IEnumerable<Stuff> stuffs)
    {
```

// Stuff is a poco - no logic..

```
        CheckIfOnDispatcher(); // all well

        if (!stuffs.Any())
        {
            return false;
        }

        var failureText = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return GetStuffDetails(DataService, stuffs);
        }).ConfigureAwait(true);

        CheckIfOnDispatcher(); // here its not on dispatcher anymore
```

The Check method was added to debug whats happening:

```
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    void CheckIfOnDispatcher()
    {
        if (Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread.CurrentThread) == null)
        {
            UserFeedback.ShowFeedback($"Not on GUI: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
```

After the await Task.Run, somethimes only, it will not return to the main thread but continue on a Worker thread.

This behavior really only happens on a win32 client, if we call it from a Windows Form client or C# WPF client, no problem. 
It looks like the main thread from the win32 MFC application has some special behavior but i cant find any documentation about it.

Are we setting the context in the wrong way?
I've also tried to open the dialog minimized from the beginning one, and hide it again, but this also did not work well (Instead of setting the context)

PS: UserFeedback is calling MessageBox which works also without a Dispatcher...

TIA,

Marco

Comment: `context = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext();` This will capture the value of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`, so this will only work if you're on a WPF context to begin with

Comment: Yes, you are right. But i've also tried to show the window and force the creation of the dispatcher - which also did not work. How can i ensure that the dispatcher will be there?

Comment: What is exactly Win32 client? I wonder how could the first `CheckIfOnDispatcher` work?

Comment: It's a MFC native C++.

Comment: As you are calling an async function, could it be that the native client doesn't wait until the async result arrives and shoots down the thread? This could explain the behaviour you encounter.

Comment: No because it continues to run until I call the view.ShowDialog() which modal. I'm still on C# code by then. The windows gets displayed, but no data is filled as the bindings all miss the dispatcher.

Comment: By the way i've added break points before the await and after - it's on main thread befire and after the await back to the worker thread even though i set the configureawait(true) - as the worker thread would be sharing the same context - which is as far as i understand possible.

Comment: @Vlad - you might be right - all other dialogs execute async code after ShowDialog - this one does it before. I'm investigating in this direction

Comment: I've added a break point on the C++ code after the call to the dialog and it's not reaching it. So the main thread from the C++ native mfc code is not continuing. We have no idea why this happens but we've found a workaround. We added a handler to the loaded event of the window and we starting the async stuff there. Now everything works fine. We will be checking the error on a smaller test app in the newar future. Thanks guys.